# Want to "ay" at the end of word

Tags: javascript

This code reverses the string and I want to add "ay" at the end of the word.

```
var string = prompt("Enter string:");
var strLen = string.length;

for(var i = strLen-1; i >= 0; i--){
   document.writeln(string[i]);
}
```

Comment: End of what word? Also [do not use `document.write` or `document.writeLn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @evolutionxbox May be end of each word)) Because if he want just add "ay" at the end of whole string then it is very strange question)))

Comment: Does this answer your question [Split string into words in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927223/split-string-into-words-in-javascript)

Comment: You do not need a loop; you can handle everything with a simple RegExp and `String.prototype.replace()`: `const output = input.replace(/([A-Za-z]+)/gi, $1 => $1.split('').reverse().join('') + 'ay')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
    var string = prompt("Enter string:");
    string = string.split("").reverse().join("");
    string += "ay";

    document.write(string)
```