# Separate each sentence using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to separate each sentence from text into an array item using jQuery.

Let's say I have this text:

> jQuery Fundamentals is designed to get you comfortable working through common problems you'll be called upon to solve using jQuery. Both versions 1.x and 2.x of jQuery support "current-1 versions" (meaning the current stable version of the browser and the version that preceded it) of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

I need to achieve this result:

```
Array (
    [0] = "jQuery Fundamentals is designed to get you comfortable working through common problems you'll be called upon to solve using jQuery."
    [1] = "Both versions 1.x and 2.x of jQuery support "current-1 versions" (meaning the current stable version of the browser and the version that preceded it) of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera."
)
```

Note that in the sentences there might be "." or other symbols, so I'm not sure if .split() will achieve the proper result.

I prefer to write code my own, so it will be great if answers suggest only the method achieving the result, or your thoughts of doing it.

Comment: perhaps a regex...splitting on dots unless they come after a digit?

Comment: Simple answer: You can't! A simple code will not know what is a sentence and what not. Split it by `.` and you would split it on the `1.x` and `2.x` too. Split it on `. ` (*space behind*) and you will possible not match split correct when space is missing. So basically it is not possible on a safty way ...

Comment: First of all you have to define what is a sentence. If you have managed that task you can go on :)

Comment: To add to @nem035 and @eisbehr, do a split with `.` taking care of numbers and then trim white spaces. You should have sentences then.

Comment: Well, and then you write about an js object in one sentence, like `object.test`. Here you go ... @VivekPradhan

Comment: Example: "The fox jump over a car, a bus etc. and survived. That was awesome!"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but as @Glufu said, there might be a sentence that have ". ", so that won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into sentences in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914629/split-string-into-sentences-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914629/split-string-into-sentences-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this.!!!

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var str = "jQuery Fundamentals is designed to get you comfortable working through common problems you'll be called upon to solve using jQuery. Both versions 1.x and 2.x of jQuery support 'current-1 versions' (meaning the current stable version of the browser and the version that preceded it) of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.";
            var lines = str.split('. '); //dot with space(your case)
            jQuery.each(lines, function(){
                alert(this);
            });
        });
```

Comment: It was alredy pointed out in the comments that this don't work! Beside this, your code has some other design problems and is not really great code ...

Answer (score 0):

Usually we do this type of work either by split() method or regular expression.
If you know the type of text explicitly like having a set of pattern, then you can go with regular expression. But sometimes regular expressions are slower than some other basic methods.

In your case, a simple suggestion: you can go with split() by '. ' -> dot and a space separator to get next line. Further more, search the next line having first character as a capital one.

```
str.split(". "); //search for a dot along with a space.
```

Comment: It was alredy pointed out in the comments that this don't work!