# How can I insert Html tags into incoming dynamic text

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-text

I have some incoming text from a database that's generated dynamically and it is being placed into a div, I'll call it:

```
<div id="dynamicText"> ${dataBase.text} </div>
```

What I want to do is dynamically place p tags inside of the database.text based on the number of complete sentences. So for example before the first line in database.text we have a starting p tag, then after the 8th completed
sentence we have an ending p tag. Then repeat for every 8 sentences.

This is the expression I'm using to count the number of occurring sentences:

`/\w[.?!](\s|$)/g`

Ultimately here is the simplified code I have so far within an ajax request:

```
/* The reg expression for counting sentences */

 let re;
 re = /\w[.?!](\s|$)/g

const dataBase = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

/* Pull the text out the database object for counting sentences */
const dataBaseString = dataBase.text;


/* Count the number of senteces */
let count = (dataBaseString.match(re) || []).length;


const output = ` 
   <div class="ajaxText">
      ${dataBase.text }
   </div>
`;


document.getElementById('dynamicText').innerHTML = output;
```

I have no problems counting the sentences, the roadblock I'm running into is putting the p tags into the incoming text. I tried using `insertAdjacentHTML()` but I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null` error.

Any ideas on how this can be done, or if this can be done?

Comment: I'm confused. Currently you match sentences but don't do anything with them. In the code you posted `count` isn't used for anything after you've done the match. There is also no reference to `insertAdjacentHTML()` that you discuss.

Comment: The reason why I wasn't doing anything with `count` is because after I was able to match the sentences, I ran into problems figuring out how to insert the p tags inside of the text and break it down into paragraphs based on the matching `count`. Which **mkbctrl** was able to figure that part out. I didn't include `insertAdjacentHTML()` because that part of the code I came up with didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voila!

Based on responses from:
[Split string into sentences in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914629/split-string-into-sentences-in-javascript)
and 
[Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

I have created a solution that I believe is a viable one. I am splitting the whole string ( database.text ) into and array of phrazes, than I create the chunks of 8 of phrazes, and in the end I append them to the wrapper.

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

const text = `... your stringified content`

const array = text.replace(/([.?!])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|")

function chunker(array, chunkSize) {
  console.log(array)
  return [].concat.apply([],
    array.map(function(el, i) {
      return i % chunkSize ? [] : [array.slice(i, i + chunkSize)];
    })
  );
}

const paragraphs = chunker(array, 8)

paragraphs.forEach((el) => {
    const p = document.createElement('p')
  p.innerText = el
  wrapper.append(p)
})
```

here is a JSfiddle I have prepared for you: https://jsfiddle.net/mkbctrlll/d5r38whL/35/