# JavaScript replaceAll case-insensitive search using variable rather than a string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, replaceall

I want to do a JavaScript `replaceAll()` using a variable (rather than a string) in a case-insensitive search, but also retaining the case of the matched text (in the return).  For example,

```js
console.log('doc.p:', doc.p.toString().substring(0, 26))
var query = this.manager.store.get('q').value.toString();
console.log('query:', query, '| type:', typeof(query))
console.log(doc.p.toString().replaceAll(/(dna)/gi, '***$1***'))
console.log(doc.p.toString().replaceAll(/(query)/gi, '***$1***'))
```

is giving

```json
doc.p: DNA deoxyribonucleic acid     // target text
query: dna | type: string            // query text
***DNA*** deoxyribonucleic acid ...  // [success] case-insensitive search; case-sensitive return
DNA deoxyribonucleic acid ...        // [failure] I've also tried (e.g.) $query, $(query), ... here
```

I was motivated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/19161971/1904943 , and also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/1904943

Once working, I'll be replacing the '***' (solely for testing / illustration) with HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you want is to create a dynamic regular expression, instead of hardcoding it. This is done with the help of. RegExp constructor, which takes the string representation of a regexp and flags (I messed the string capitalization to demo the preservation of case):

```js
string1 = 'DnA deoxyribonucleic acid'
string2 = 'DNA deoxyribonucleic aCId'

const replacer = (str, replace) => {
  const re = new RegExp(`(${replace})`, 'gi')
  return str.replaceAll(re, '***$1***')
}

console.log(replacer(string1, 'dna'))
console.log(replacer(string2, 'acid'))
```

Comment: Love both of these answers (@IvanD | @Nikhil Patel); accepting IvanD's as the function looks quite useful, generally and I learned something new!  Many thanks to all who replied!!  :-D

Answer (score 1):

You need create regex expression using `RegExp` -

```
var reg = new RegExp(`(${query})`, "gi")
```

```js
var doc = "DNA deoxyribonucleic acid";
var query = "dna"
var exp = `(${query})`
var reg = new RegExp(exp, "gi")
var result = doc.replaceAll(reg, "***$1***");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `replace` already has the functionality of doing a case-insensitive search while also retaining the original case of a capture group, e.g.

```js
var input = "DNA deoxyribonucleic acid";
var output = input.replace(/(dna)/ig, "***$1***");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Don't forget the `g`lobal flag.

Comment: Much appreciated; h/e, I wanted a solution using variables. ;-)  Thank you for your response!